# Add "post option" support parameter in custom post type using Hueman Theme?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, add-theme-support

I created a custom post type and I want to add "post option" in my custom post type where in I would be able to select if I would include a sidebar or not, a layout option. I would like to ask if what support parameter I would used to achieved this using Hueman Theme. Here is what I want to achieve.

[image]

```
function rds_blog_custom_init() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name'                  => _x( 'RDs Blog', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Blog Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => _x( 'RDs Blog', 'admin menu' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'RDs Blog', 'add new on admin bar' ),
        'add_ new'              => _x( 'Add New', 'blog item' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Blog Item' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Blog Item' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Blog Item' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Blog Item' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Blogs' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Blog' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Nothing Found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Nothing found in trash' ),
        );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'taxonomies'            => array('category'),
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => '' ),
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'menu_position'         => null,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'post-formats', 'What parameter I would used here?' )
);

register_post_type( 'rds_blog', $args );
```

Comment: What have you coded so far?

Comment: The above is just what I've got

Comment: You want to add support for a custom functionality, which you can not know how it works if you don't show us the code.